# Where does God draw the line when it comes to Sin?

Tags: sin, nature-of-god, soteriology, nature-of-man

So I've read 1 John alot and I understand that I cannot continue to sin if I want to be a child of God's.

> **1 John 1:6** (NIV)
>
> 6 If we claim to have fellowship with him and yet walk in the
>   darkness, we lie and do not live out the truth.

But then at the same time, if we accomplish the call to be holy and to be righteous and to be free of sin then we are not children of God.

> **1 John 1:8** (NIV)
>
> 8 If we claim to be without sin, we deceive ourselves and the truth
>   is not in us.

I'm personally struggling with this very line in my own life. I don't hate people, because I know that I'm commanded to love. But when it comes to my own desires of the flesh I continually fail. I have no self control, I cannot even get out of bed when my alarm goes off lol.

Where does God draw this line? does He give us any more insight into the battle with sin through scripture? So I ask again, where does God draw the line when it comes to Sin?

Comment: Glad to know that I am not the only one who continually fall to the desires...

Comment: Continually sinning is a problem for all of us.  Even Paul said so in [Romans 7:18-20](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%207:18-20&version=NIV)

Comment: Notice that 1 John 1:8 does not say "if we accomplish the call...to be free of sin, we are not children of God." Instead it says "If we **claim** to be without sin..." In other words, it is saying that it is impossible to be without sin, and someone who says they are without sin is either lying, or so ill-informed (Norman Greenbaum?) that they are deceiving themselves.

Comment: @Flimzy good point.

Comment: @JonathonByrd Also notice that 1 John 1:6 is symptomatic; it tells us the standard to help us determine whether we are REALLY in fellowship with God and the brethren. If we keep choosing sin and being at odds with God and men, then we are not in fellowship with God. This tells me that true fellowship with God is life-changing; if we are not fellowshiping with God His way, then we are not bearing spiritual fruit.

Answer (score 4):

Well, taking advntage of the God's mercy and forgivness is certainy not a right thing. In my opinion, unless we compeletly sway out of God's way, we should not worry to much about what kind of sins we do everyday; unless it is serious. We are humans, after all, we all make mistakes. Like Jesus said in the bible:

> [Matthew 26:41:](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2026:41&version=NCV)
>   41 Stay awake and pray for strength against temptation. The spirit wants to do what is right, but the body is weak."

In the end, it is not how we can avoid sinning, but it is how we can be more like Christ. We will always have transgressions, but we should be trying to make it better.

Answer (score 2):

Our life here on earth is a process.  If we've accepted Christ as our Savior, then we're supposed to be striving for the life he lived.  Think of it like an onion.  Each time we learn something new about ourselves, another layer is pealed away.  If you're continuously sinning in the same way, then perhaps you've not gotten to the root of why you sin in that particular way.  Obviously, we know the end.  God has already forgiven all our sins, but we still will give an account for all we did here on Earth.  There will be days where we're "better" than others, but ultimately, I think God looks at the condition of our heart while we're doing the things we do.  Whatever they may be.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand the context of the bible always states that man is sinful in nature. The scripture is stating that if you choose to walk around saying that you are without sin, then you are in fact lieing to yourself.

Every person struggles with some form of sin in their life. Whether it being judgemental of your siblings or neighbors, an addiction to an earthly object (i.e. pizza/mountain dew/video games =D), or lusting over someone whom you may or may not know.

He's just saying don't lie to yourself and saying you are without sin because no person is without sin.

Comment: My personal opinion is that saying "man is sinful in nature" encourages sins.

Answer (score 1):

Literally, the line is drawn when an unbeliever [blasphemes the Holy Spirit,](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Mat&c=12&v=31&t=KJV#s=941031) rejecting Him and His work of drawing them to God. It’s not easy to tell when that line has been crossed, however.

In the believer’s case, the line is drawn in [Hebrews 10:26,](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Hbr&c=10&t=KJV#s=1143026) when one sins willfully after knowing fellowship with God (or, "the truth"), and at that point, one looks fearfully to the judgment of God ahead.

But your reluctance to sin and acknowledgment about your weaknesses shows that you are nowhere near these lines; you still have a conscience and a heart to do what’s right by God, which people crossing “the line” do not have or care about.

Your feelings are similar to the person who started weightlifting or dieting, and after a week notices no changes and starts to question the whole process. But the spiritual life is just that – a process, and it takes time for fruit to grow. But that fruit of the Spirit does indeed grow when we feed the plant properly, not with poison from the world, but water from the Word. You aren’t anywhere near the line; you are in the place where Steve Jobs said: [“Stay hungry.”](http://news.stanford.edu/news/2005/june15/jobs-061505.html) You [hunger and thirst for righteousness,](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Mat&c=5&t=KJV#s=934006) and that shows that you have a solid footing in the kingdom.

You are not deceiving yourself regarding sin, but confessing your inadequacy to live in your own strength, so you are in a good place. Paul talked about this struggle in [Romans 7:13-24](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Rom&c=7&t=KJV#s=1053013) (and deliverance in 7:25).

Instead of looking for a line, look to the fact that His compassion fails not and His mercies are new every morning (see [Lamentations 3:22-24).](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Lam&c=3&t=KJV#s=800022)

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to one thought. We are all Gods children. We are made in his imagine. He loves us to no end and there is no end to his forgiveness. But this doesn't mean you can sin without an thought of Gods retribution. At some point you are not a Christian even though you still call yourself Christian. 
  Also, many Christians worry endlessly about bothmajor and minor sins of the flesh. God is aware of our humanity and it's pitfalls and wishes us to grow in our Christianity and uses these pitfalls to help us grow.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This doesn't really have much to do with your answer, but I find that sharing the following tends to help new visitors avoid mistaking the purpose of this site. I do hope to see more from you!  When you get a chance, please see [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)